# find unique element in go slice which is filled stdin

Tags: algorithm, go

need to output to the terminal a int that does not have a pair. My problem is that I don’t understand how not to output a number when it is no longer unique.

here is my code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var arr []int
    var unique int
    var input int
    for true {
        keys := make(map[int]bool)
        fmt.Scan(&input)
        arr = append(arr, input)
        fmt.Println(arr)
        for _, entry := range arr {
            if _, value := keys[entry]; !value {
                keys[entry] = false
                unique = entry
                fmt.Println("UNIQ", unique)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to get a good answer, please work on clarifying your question. Define the problem precisely.

Comment: Start by writing a function which does the algorithmic work and do not mix that with parsing  input. You first have to read the data, then process it, then output the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, I would like to make some comments.

1. The **keys** map you create is erased at every iteration. Alternatively, while you store your **arr** permanently, you could do the same with this map.
2. **Maps** in Golang return two values (valueType,bool).

```golang
value, ok := keys[entry]
```

**ok** is assigned with the value of true if that entry exists. Otherwise it gets the value false.

While you need to verify the existence of an integer in a set, you don't need the boolean value here. You can simply create the following map:

```golang
keys := map[int]struct{}
...

//add element to map
keys[element] = struct{}{}
```

This way the second value of the returned ones can verify the existence or not.

Further suggestions and troubleshooting may vary depending on the definition of the problem.

1. You need to print out every element that is unique

In this case, you don't need to iterate over the **arr** slice.
You can just count the occurrences of each element using a map[int]int.
(For occurrences greater that 2, you don't need to take any action). Finally, you iterate through that map and print out the elements with 1 occurrences.

2. You need to print only if the last inserted element is unique

In this case, you don't need to iterate the **arr** every time as well. You can just check the **keys** map for the existence of the last inserted element.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. I am sure that I will cope with the task